# I can no longer use my Kingston DTSE9 flash drive because it is 'write-protected'. How can I remove the write-protection?

Tags: mac, usb, formatting

Disk Utility won't allow me to Erase or Repair the drive, it will only let me verify it.

Clicking on Disk Partition, I get the following message:
This partition cannot be modified. This disk is not writable and can not be partitioned.

I used this thumb drive to transfer files from my mac to a PC, and it became write protected after a transfer from one to the other.

[image: Screen Shot 1]

[image: Screen Shot 2]

Answer (score 2):

Before you do anything serious...

Rarely some memory cards/Pen Drives are having physical button/switch (yes a miniature mechanical switch) to make it write protect..

Check your pendrive to make sure you did not accidentally activate it by puling/pushing the USB.

Comment: This is a good point.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
See Buscar's response first. If this is not the case:

FAT-32 formatted flash drives should not spontaneously become write-protected; it's a sign that either the drive's controller (yes, flash drives have controllers) is corrupted requiring a reformat, or the drive is physically failing. The two aren't mutually exclusive. Every solution I found perusing Google provide a fix within Windows, rather than OSX. I highly suspect that the drive itself is failing and you should backup all data on it and purchase a new one

[How to remove a write protection from your USB memory Stick:](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/272402-32-flash-drive)

> 1. Shutdown your computer or laptop
> 2. Insert USB Memory Stick into your laptop or Computer
> 3. Turn on computer and then immediately start pressing (F8) key then Advanced Boot Options screen will come up
> 4. Select Safe Mode with Command Prompt
> 5. After loading files if your USB Memory Stick drive letter is (G) for example then write as
> 6. C:\windows\system32>G: and press enter
> 7. G:>format G: and press enter
> 8. If ask you (Y/N) then press (Y) and press enter
> 9. Now a full format will start which remove write protection from USB Memory Stick.

[Remove without reformatting:](http://blog.premiumusb.com/2011/07/usb-flash-drive-write-protection/)

> - An alternative option is to access your system’s registry.
> - Once you plug in your flash drive, hit the “Start” menu and select “Run” and type “regedit” for the Registry Editor.
> - Go to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies.  You’ll have to click through a few levels of folders to get to
>     “StorageDevicePolicies”.
> - Next, right-click on “WriteProtect” and choose “Modify”.  Type in 0 and press “Enter”  Now your drive will be set without write
>     protection.